# Find the degree of a splitting field when $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, field-theory

Given a prime $p$ what would be the splitting field of $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Let $f(x)=x^p-1$ for prime $p$.

I was thinking that this might have something to do with the identity $\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+x+1$. Not sure though.

Comment: What is $f$? Also, that "identity" you wrote down is just an expression, not an equation.

Comment: I fixed it, now $f(x)$ has been defined.

Comment: The splitting field of $x^n-1$ is the cyclotomic field of $n$th roots of unity. If $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then the roots of $x^n-1$ are precisely $\zeta,\zeta^2,\ldots,\zeta^{n-1},\zeta^n=1$. The degree of splitting field is then the degree of the monic irreducible for $\zeta$. When $n=p$ is prime, do you know whether $x^{p-1}+\cdots+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Isn't $x^{p-1}+...+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? Can we in general say that for any integer $n$ the equation $x^{n}=1$ has $n$ solutions that are the roots of unity?